# How to sort/order tuple of ip address in python

Tags: python, sorting

kindly help me out to address IP address sorting

Input IP address:

```
[{'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.4.1'}]
```

Expected Output IP address:

```
[{'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.4.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}]
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you explain more about how you want the IP addresses to be sorted?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks for your reply, Prunus Persica, i need output something like ['10.91.1.1', '10.219.1.1', '10.91.4.1', '10.219.4.1'] First sort of items are Eth0 ie., 10.91.1.1 and 10.219.1.1 Second sort of items are Eth1 ie., 10.91.4.1 and 10.219.4.1 Here we are soring eth0 and eth1 based on their order, not all IP's sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a = [{'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}, {'host': : '10.91.4.1'}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.')))

# [{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.'))[::-1])

# [{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, Zipa, i need output something like ['10.91.1.1', '10.219.1.1', '10.91.4.1', '10.219.4.1'] First sort of items are Eth0 ie., 10.91.1.1 and 10.219.1.1 Second sort of items are Eth1 ie., 10.91.4.1 and 10.219.4.1 Here we are soring eth0 and eth1 based on their order, not all IP's sorting

Comment: Hi Zipa, when i use

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.'))[::-1])
encountered with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Error,
kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[{'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.4.1'}] 

c=[]
for i in a:
  c.append(i["host"])
print(c)
import ipaddress
sortedkey = sorted(c, key = ipaddress.IPv4Address)
print(sortedkey)
```

> ['10.91.1.1', '10.91.4.1', '10.219.1.1', '10.219.4.1']

Comment: thanks for your reply, Salim, i need output something like
['10.91.1.1', '10.219.1.1', '10.91.4.1', '10.219.4.1']

First sort of items are Eth0 ie., 10.91.1.1 and 10.219.1.1
Second sort of items are Eth1 ie., 10.91.4.1 and 10.219.4.1

Here we are soring eth0 and eth1 based on their order, not all IP's sorting