# Encountered with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

Reference : [How to sort/order tuple of ip address in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117764/how-to-sort-order-tuple-of-ip-address-in-python)

Used :

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.'))[::-1])
```

Logic
to sort a tuple, encountered with

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Error,

kindly help me out

Comment: Please the the take to debug, make a for loop, split and convert to int

Comment: Take a look at what `x['host']` contains. I suspect you'll find it's got components that aren't valid numbers (e.g. in this case, `'' Error,"`).

Comment: One of the `i`'s is not a number.

Comment: `for x in a:
        try:
            print(tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.')))
        except:
            print(">>", x)`

Comment: Could you show us the value of `a`? The problem is in there. At least one of the values is not a valid IPv4 address.

Comment: a = [{'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}, {'host': : '10.91.4.1'}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.')))

# [{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.'))[::-1])

# [{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]

FYI : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117764/how-to-sort-order-tuple-of-ip-address-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some character that is not a digit or a "." in your input data (the array `a`).

We don't know your input data, so I can't point directly to the error, but it seems like one of the values in `a` could contain the string `'' Error,`.

This works fine for me (does not give an error):

```
a=[{'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.4.1'}]

print(sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.'))[::-1]) )
```

It gives this output:

```
[{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]
```

Did you try to run that exact code?

Comment: a = [{'host': u'10.219.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.91.1.1'}, {'host': u'10.219.4.1'}, {'host': : '10.91.4.1'}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.')))

# [{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: tuple(int(i) for i in x['host'].split('.'))[::-1])

# [{'host': '10.91.1.1'}, {'host': '10.219.1.1'}, {'host': '10.91.4.1'}, {'host': '10.219.4.1'}]

FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117764/how-to-sort-order-tuple-of-ip-address-in-python

Comment: @SujithKumar Yes, but the problem is that it works well with that specific data when I try it. So I assume you are not using that data?

Comment: @SujithKumar Ah, you need to post the code by editing the question. It can't be copied from a comment so we can test it, as newlines are zapped from comments, and they are important in Python.